# Deriving error of Simpson's rule from Taylor expansion

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am reading a numerical analysis textbook. In the chapter numerical integration, I followed one exercise as it gives the hint:

> For interval $[a,b]$, let $h=\frac{b-a}{2}$. Use Taylor expansion to derive
> $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=2hf(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{h^3}{3}f''(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{h^5}{60}f^{(4)}(\frac{a+b}{2})+O(h^7)+\cdots$$

I got that expression without difficulty. Next I tried to use Taylor expansion to Simpson's rule to get:
$$I(f)=\frac{h}{3}[f(a)+4f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b)]=2hf(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{h^3}{3}f''(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{h^5}{36}f^{(4)}(\frac{a+b}{2})+O(h^7)+\cdots$$

The error $E(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f-I(f)$ is:
$$-\frac{1}{90}h^{5}f^{(4)}(\frac{a+b}{2})+O(h^7)+\cdots$$

However, as we know the error of Simpson's rule should be $-\frac{1}{90}h^{5}f^{(4)}(\xi)$ where $\xi\in(a,b)$. Since I got the fixed midpoint $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$, how to 'prove' that $\xi$ in error term? I have viewed this kind of question on MSE, but none of these answers used Taylor expansion method.

So I came out one idea, suppose $f^{(4)}$ and $f^{(5)}$ are both continuous, how about changing the $h^5$ term to
$$-\frac{1}{90}h^5 f^{(4)}(\xi)+\left(-\frac{1}{90}h^{5}f^{(4)}(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{1}{90}h^5 f^{(4)}(\xi)\right)=-\frac{1}{90}h^5 f^{(4)}(\xi)+\frac{1}{90}h^5\cdot\left(\left|\frac{a+b}{2}-\xi\right|f^{(5)}(\eta)\right)$$

Comment: I suggest using the exact formula for the Taylor remainder, either the integral form or the Lagrange form. What's gonna happen is that by linearity, the error of Simpson's rule applied to $f$ is the error of Simpson's rule applied to the remainder term of the Taylor expansion. Then you might need another step by applying the intermediate value theorem to get existence of $\xi$.

Comment: @Kakashi Do you mean I need to find the terms include $f^{(4)}(\xi_1)$ in interval $(a,\frac{a+b}{2})$ and $f^{(4)}(\xi_2)$ in interval $(\frac{a+b}{2},b)$?

Comment: I tried it once time, but I found something's wrong in applying the intermediate value theorem because the coefficients of $h^5$, one is $\frac{1}{60}f^{(4)}(\eta_1),\eta_1\in(a,b)$, while another one is $\frac{1}{36}f^{(4)}(\eta_2),\eta_2\in(a,b)$. They cannot combine together.

Comment: Use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_kernel_theorem. It's applying the error functional $L$ for SImpson's rule to the integral form of the remainder. See page 151 of "Introduction to Numerical Analysis" by Burlisch and Stoer.

Comment: Thank you for your reference. I also thought out another way to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Kakashi's comment, I solved it with integral remainders in Taylor expansion.
It's well-known that for a function $f$ with at least $n+1$ order derivatives, it could be expanded as:
$$f(h)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}h^{k}+\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{h}f^{(n+1)}(t)(h-t)^{n}\mathrm{d}t$$
For interval $[a,b]$, let $h=\frac{b-a}{2}$, define error function $E(u)$ when $u\in[0,h]$:
$$E(u)=\int_{-u}^{u}f(t)\mathrm{d}t-\frac{u}{3}\left(f(-u)+4f(0)+f(u)\right)$$
It's easy to know $E(0)=E'(0)=E''(0)=0$ and $E^{(3)}(u)=\frac{u}{3}(f^{(3)}(-u)-f^{(3)}(u))$.
$$E(h)=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{h}(f^{(3)}(-t)-f^{(3)}(t))t(h-t)^2\mathrm{d}t$$
By integral mean value theorem, there exists $\eta\in(0,h)$ and $\theta\in(0,\eta)$ that
$$E(h)=\frac{f^{(3)}(-\eta)-f^{(3)}(\eta)}{180\eta}h^5=\frac{f^{(4)}(\theta)(-2\eta)}{180\eta}h^5=-\frac{h^5}{90}f^{(4)}(\theta)$$